# Find all continuous functions with the property that f(x)f(y)f(z) = 3, for every x, y, z ∈ R, with x + y + z = 0.

Tags: continuity, functional-equations

Find all continuous functions with the property that f(x)f(y)f(z) = 3, for every x, y, z ∈ R, with x + y + z = 0.

I am quite new to new to functional equations and I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while.

I tried to somehow get and transform into a Cauchy equation but failed during the process.

Any help would be slightly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  One example should be obvious.  Can you find another?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, note that $f(0)^3=3$, by plugging $x=y=z=0$. This way, we have that $f(0)=\sqrt[3]{3}$, so let us denote $g(x)=f(x)/\sqrt[x]{3}$. The original condition tells us that $g(x)g(y)g(z)=1$ for every $x+y+z=0$, and $g(0)=1$ by construction.

Now, by plugging $y=-x, z=0$, we have that $g(x)g(-x)g(0)=1$; or $g(-x)=g(x)^{-1}$. In particular, this tells us that $g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$.

To conclude, note that for every $x$ and $y$, we can take $z=x+y$, so
$$ g(x)g(y)g(-x-y)=1 \implies g(x)g(y)=g(x+y). $$
This is now a Cauchy functional equation. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Thank you very much @Nicolás Vilches, I think I can conclude from there. Much appreciated!

Comment: sorry for asking but I think that when z is not 0 the conclusion of the functional equation does not apply to the initial case. Do you have any ideas or did I misunderstand something? Thank you!